# How to force any entered value in Excel to convert to negative

Tags: excel

How can I force any number in Excel to convert to a negative?

For example, if a user enters -10 in A1 then it should do nothing, if 10 is entered then it should *-1 to convert to a negative.

I already have the following custom cell format applied to the whole sheet: #,##0.00_ ;(#,##0.00) meaning that any negative numbers are shown in brackets. But A1 can only contain a negative number, so I want it to automatically convert to a negative if the user enters a positive.

How can I do this?

Comment: You will need vba in a Worksheet_Change Event.

Comment: Can't you just use data validation only allowing a whole number (or decimal) less than 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the following Event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A1 As Range
    Set A1 = Range("A1")
    If Intersect(Target, A1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(A1) Then
        If A1 < 0 Then Exit Sub
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            A1 = -A1
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

*Unlike Data Validation, it will not reject a positive input, it will just make it negative.*

**Edit#1:**

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#2:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim negatives As Range, r As Range, rLOOK As Range
    Set negatives = Range("negatives")
    Set rLOOK = Intersect(negatives, Target)
    If rLOOK Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each r In rLOOK
        If IsNumeric(r) Then
            If r > 0 Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                    r.Value = -r.Value
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Here we:

- get the intersection
- test the intersection
- loop over the intersection

Comment: You'll have to forgive me, I'm a complete novice when it comes to the VB console... where do I put that code, and then how do I "save" it and make it run once I've copied it over?

Comment: @Stotty146  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Ignore my last... I managed to play around and figured it out!

Comment: How would I then amend the above to get it to apply to multiple cells?

Comment: @Stotty146  The coding would depend on exactly **which set of cells** the macro must monitor.

Comment: It's not a particular set, it's just random ones throughout the worksheet. 3 cells in total (including A1 as above) must have negative values, but they're not in any particular set.

Comment: @Stotty146  We need to be able to tell the code which cells to monitor..........think of the code as a clever intern.  If you tell the intern what to do, there is a reasonable chance it will get done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129641/discussion-between-stotty146-and-garys-student).

Comment: @Stotty146  See my **EDIT#2**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ABS` for the absolute (positive) value

```
=-ABS(A1)
```

Comment: OP wants to change the value entered in the cell that the value was entered.  A formula will not do that.

Comment: Agreed, on re-reading the question I was just going to add that another column will be required.

Comment: So I could get B2 to show the negative value of A1, but how could I get A1 to update automatically and show that same negative?

Comment: See Gary's answer - you will need to use VBA. Alternatively you can force the user to input negative numbers using data validation